# Counting fractions with $n$ digits in the numerator and denominator

Tags: number-theory, combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, fractions

Playing around with fractions, I eventually had to consider the following question:

> Is there a formula for counting how many proper fractions in lowest terms with
>   $n$ base-$b$ digits in both the numerator and the denominator are there?

So, for instance, things like $0$, $\frac24$, $\frac22$, and $\frac43$ don't count.

My first thought was that they'd be related to triangular numbers, but this seems to count the fractions not in lowest terms as well. I presume the final formula can be expressed as a triangular number minus some correction, but I can't figure out what that correction term ought to be.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean exactly $n$ digits or at most $n$?

Comment: Srivatsan, "exactly".

Comment: Basically you want the number of pairs $(r,s)$, each $\in[b^{n-1},b^n-1]$, with $r<s$ and $\gcd(r,s)=1$. I'm doubtful there's a pretty formula for this.

Comment: Would [tag:elementary-number-theory] be appropriate to add? I'm not sure...

Comment: I googled the first few numbers for $b=10$ and came up with no results at all, neither at the integer search database. Looks bad for your formula.

Comment: Huh, $1, 6, 26, 111, 440, 1767, 7057, 28305, 113158$ (the sequence for $b=2$) isn't in the OEIS either... this looks hard.

Comment: Short of it having something to do with the Euler totient function, I have nothing to add.

Comment: Each term in the $b=2$ sequence is pretty close to 4 times the previous term, as one would expect.

Comment: @J. M., I'm having trouble reproducing your numbers. The 3-bit numbers are 4, 5, 6, and 7. The reduced proper fractions are 4/5, 4/7, 5/6, 5/7, 6/7. That's 5; you say 6. The 4-bit fractions are 8/9, 8/11, 8/13, 8/15, 9/10, 9/11, 9/13, 9/14, 10/11, 10/13, 11/12, 11/13, 11/14, 11/15, 12/13, 13/14, 13/15, 14/15, which is 18; how do you get 26?

Comment: @Gerry: Ooh, you're right; apparently I screwed up in my program somewhere. Here's what I got after fixing my program: $1, 5, 18, 82, 306, 1251, 4952, 19978, 79630$

Comment: ...by the way, @Gerry, I would have understood tagging this [tag:number-theory], but why precisely the analytic sort?

Comment: @J. M., in my answer, I used the result, $\Phi(x)$ asymptotic to $(3/\pi^2)x^2$, which I think of as analytic number theory. And I'm sure if anyone is going to get a more accurate answer than mine, some analytic techniques will be needed. But I won't object if someone re-tags the question.

Answer (score 4):

For fixed $s$, the number of $r$, $1\le r\le s$, $\gcd(r,s)=1$, is denoted $\phi(s)$, and is called the Euler phi-function. For fixed $x$, the number of pairs $(r,s)$ with $1\le r\le s\lt x$, $\gcd(r,s)=1$, in other words the number of proper reduced fractions with denominator less than $x$, is $\sum_{s\lt x}\phi(s)$. Call this $\Phi(x)$. It is known that $\Phi(x)$ is asymptotic to $(3/\pi^2)x^2$. The number of proper reduced fractions with denominator of exactly $n$ digits in base $b$ is then $\Phi(b^n)-\Phi(b^{n-1})$, which is roughly $(3/\pi^2)(b^{2n}-b^{2n-2})$. Now you want to know how many of these have an $n$-digit numerator. For $s$ just over $b^{n-1}$, hardly any will qualify. For $s$ close to $b^n$, it seems plausible to me that about $b-1$ out of every $b$ will qualify, simply because $b-1$ out of every $b$ numbers near $b^n$ have $n$ digits. So I'd split the difference and figure that we're looking at about $(3/\pi^2)(b^{2n}-b^{2n-2})(b-1)/(2b)$.